# Display array ratings according to user's input in alert

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to write a program that allows users to view only hotels with 4 stars ratings. Whenever I run this code, I keep on getting back all of the objects within the array, instead of just 'Hilton' and 'Holiday Inn'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
     var hotels = ['Marriot', 'Hilton', 'Double Tree', 'Holiday Inn']
    var visitorRating = ['0 starts', '4 stars', '1 star', '4 stars']

    var seeHotels = prompt("Would you like to see all of the hotels whose ratings are 4 stars?");
    var fourStars = e;

    for(var e = 0; e < visitorRating.length; e++){
if(visitorRating[e].indexOf("4 stars"))
   document.write( hotels[e] + ' ' + visitorRating[e])
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few syntax errors with your code, it was missing some paranthesis here and there.

Also you should check for the condition `visitorRating[e].indexOf("4 stars") !== -1`

**DEMO**

```js
var hotels = ['Marriot', 'Hilton', 'Double Tree', 'Holiday Inn'];
var visitorRating = ['0 starts', '4 stars', '1 star', '4 stars'];

 var seeHotels = prompt("Would you like to see all of the hotels whose ratings are 4 stars?");
    var fourStars = e;

for(var e = 0; e < visitorRating.length; e++){
if(visitorRating[e].indexOf("4 stars") !== -1){
   document.write( hotels[e] + ' ' + visitorRating[e])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` if the item is not found. Since -1 is not a falsy value, in the `if` it's translated to `true`, and you get all items except the one with the index of `0`, since 0 is casted to `false`. Change the condition to:

```
visitorRating[e].indexOf("4 stars") !== -1
```

**Demo:**

```js
var hotels = ['Marriot', 'Hilton', 'Double Tree', 'Holiday Inn']
var visitorRating = ['0 starts', '4 stars', '1 star', '4 stars']

for (var e = 0; e < visitorRating.length; e++) {
  if (visitorRating[e].indexOf("4 stars") !== -1) {
    document.write(hotels[e] + ' ' + visitorRating[e] + '<br>')
  }
}
```